# Run multiple cron jobs for one PHP file

Tags: php, cron

I use `cron jobs` at 8:00. and i want my file run 3 times by different value

> Example:

```
test.php?id=1
test.php?id=2
test.php?id=3
```

How i can run top file in `cron jobs` at 8:00 simultaneously ?

Comment: 3 seperate cron jobs all scheduled to start at 8:00 or is that to obvious

Comment: _small point_ That does not look like the way to pass parameters to a cron job as they are PHP CLI scripts not web pages launched with a querystring

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i want use 20 times per 8:00, add 20 url to cronjobs ?!

Comment: Yes why not, unix will run many jobs at the same time

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you

Comment: You've shown us URL fragments - not commands executable by cron. If you want to run them all the same time, then it would be much more efficient to amend the PHP code to run as a single invocation of PHP, or do they *need* to run in parallel (if the latter then invoking them directly from cron is the wrong approach).

Answer (score 1):

You need add params to php cli script and read $argv to get this params http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php for example

```
0 8 * * * php script.php 1
0 8 * * * php script.php 2
0 8 * * * php script.php 3
```

Comment: Thank you, i wnat use cpanel cron jobs, how i add your code into cpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

Use id field as an array. For ex-

```
$ids =array('1','2','3');
```

Than use loop, and call the function. For ex-

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $this->CronFunction($id);
}
```

This way your code will execute with three different value at same time. No need create separate file for all three value.

Comment: Yea! But not all at the same time.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned to run file simultenously at 8:00

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myarray = array();
$myarray[] = 1;
$myarray[] = 2;
$myarray[] = 3;
foreach($myarray as $myarr){
    $d = $myarr;
    page_code($d);  //this function call page code in every loop and pass different value
}

function page_code($id){
    //Insert page code inside this function
}
?>
```

create array ($myarray) with all possible values. And call page code from function, inside the loop. no need to run different crone. All ids run with single cron. Tis code work for me. Thanks

Comment: Again will run sequentially and not simultaneously

Comment: other option is include_once test.php file inside function

function page_code($id){
    include_once('test.php'); 
}